# Link button issue inside gridview in sharepoint

Tags: gridview

i have link button inside gridview. can some one help me to form proper URL for this

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" >
<ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" OnClientClick="OpenDialog('/SitePages/View%20Booking.aspx?','','');return false;" ><%#Eval("Booking Name") %></asp:LinkButton>

                                     </ItemTemplate>

                                   </asp:TemplateField>
```

if i use above, than popup opens fine on link button click but if append parameter as shown below, it throws error on load itself.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" OnClientClick="OpenDialog('/SitePages/View%20Booking.aspx?BID="+ Eval("ID")+"','','');return false;" ><%#Eval("Booking Name") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

can some one help to form proper URL?

Answer (score 0):

use escape entities like \"

or you don't need to use quotes for the query string values it will work without that also

Comment: can you form it ?